# How to connect to multiple connections in angular(ngx-mqtt)

Tags: angular, mqtt

```
constructor(private mqttService: MqttService) {}
this.mqttService.connect(this.array3[0])
```

1. I am pushing the hostname, clientid and port to array3.
   I have to connect to multiple connections and I should able to subscribe for all connections topics.

Comment: connect(){this.mqttService.connect(this.array3[0])}

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69378650/edit) the question rather than trying to add code in comments.